# Visual studio 2015 change to latest dotnet sdk

Tags: visual-studio-2015, configuration, .net-core

When I changed sdk in global.json from "1.0.0-preview2-003121" to "1.0.0-preview4-004071" and restarted vs I received following error

> "The following error occured attempting to run the project model
>   server process (1.0.0-preview4-004071).
>
> Unable to start the process. No executable found matching command
>   'dotnet-projectmodel-server'."

On build I receives

> "MSB1009 Project file does not exists"

Is it any way to change dotnet sdk in vs to new version nor "1.0.0-preview2-003121"

Comment: Solution had found. VS 2017 RC :) But need project to be correctly migrated.